# Spring boot test - PowerMockito to mock and stub constructor

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-boot, powermock

Using Spring boot starter test for testing my application but I am using third party library. Lets suppose we have a class TRequest and it has some constructor and I want to mock and stub that constructor to return the result.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@PrepareForEverythingForTest
public class TestClass {

@MockBean
TRequest trequest ; 

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.whenNew(TRequest.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(trequest);

}
}
```

Now when I am trying to create the constructor using new, it is not returning the correct stubbed result.

```
  TRequest trequest1 = new TRequest("apiKey","secretKey") ; 
  trequest.equals(trequest1) ; // false but I want it to be true
```

Comment: You _probably_ need to use the `PowerMockitoRunner` in your test, before it intercepts the construct. If you want to run it with spring, take a look at `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate` aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Have used a `jackson` third party lib to test with. - getting ClassLoader exceptions because of PowerMock though.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestPowerMockito {

    @MockBean
    ObjectMapper object;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ObjectMapper.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(object);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(object, new ObjectMapper());
    }

}
```

Comment: But now @Autowired is not working in this. Unable to fetch the dependency error is coming.

Comment: Still have to annotate the class with `@SpringBootTest` - but when i do this, i get LinkageExceptions from powermock. I can't seem to find a solution right now.

Comment: Yeah same error I am getting. please follow this url https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6808 .  It seems powermockito has fixed this issue in their latest 1.6.6 version but I am unable to see how to do it.

Comment: I'm using powermock 1.6.6 and spring-boot 1.4.0 when getting these errors, so apparently it's not resolved.